# Php page isnt sending GET request on load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, class, jquery-file-upload

I'm trying to use the jQuery File Uploader, but I'm having trouble. I've downloaded the plugin from here:

```
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
```

and been through the documentation. I've got the plugin working on my site, within its own sub directory, but now I want to use the functionality on my own page and I'm having a problem.

When i navigate to the plugin pages in the subdirectory everthing works normally, but when I copy elements of the code and deploy it to my own page something is going wrong. Specifically, on the plugin page the thumbnails all show OK, even on my own server - however, when I use it on my page the thumbs arent uploading properly.

I've noticed that when the page from the plugin loads, there is GET call to the /server/php folder, which contains the file that holds the classes for the plugin, but on my page the same call doesnt run.

I have the pages online in case anyone can help:

The one that is working is here:

```
http://54.187.7.151/jQfileUpload/index.html
```

and the one that isnt is here:

```
http://54.187.7.151/div.php
```

In terms of file structure, I'm calling the handler script within the plugin from jQuery (/jQfileUpload/server/php) from 'div.php' and just (/server/php) from /jQfileUpload/index.html, since it sits in the same folder.

This has been killing me all afternoon!! Can anyone help?

JQuery for `http://54.187.7.151/jQfileUpload/index.html` (the only difference between this and div.php is the path to the handler script :

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io' ?
                '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/' : 'server/php/',
        uploadButton = $('<button/>')
            .addClass('btn btn-primary')
            .prop('disabled', true)
            .text('Processing...')
            .on('click', function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data();
                $this
                    .off('click')
                    .text('Abort')
                    .on('click', function () {
                        $this.remove();
                        data.abort();
                    });
                data.submit().always(function () {
                    $this.remove();
                });
            });
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        autoUpload: false,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
        maxFileSize: 5000000, // 5 MB
        // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
        // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
        // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
        disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
            .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
        previewMaxWidth: 100,
        previewMaxHeight: 100,
        previewCrop: true
    }).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
        data.context = $('<div/>').appendTo('#files');
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
            var node = $('<p/>')
                    .append($('<span/>').text(file.name));
            if (!index) {
                node
                    .append('<br>')
                    .append(uploadButton.clone(true).data(data));
            }
            node.appendTo(data.context);
        });
    }).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function (e, data) {
        var index = data.index,
            file = data.files[index],
            node = $(data.context.children()[index]);
        if (file.preview) {
            node
                .prepend('<br>')
                .prepend(file.preview);
        }
        if (file.error) {
            node
                .append('<br>')
                .append($('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error));
        }
        if (index + 1 === data.files.length) {
            data.context.find('button')
                .text('Upload')
                .prop('disabled', !!data.files.error);
        }
    }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
            'width',
            progress + '%'
        );
    }).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            if (file.url) {
                var link = $('<a>')
                    .attr('target', '_blank')
                    .prop('href', file.url);
                $(data.context.children()[index])
                    .wrap(link);
            } else if (file.error) {
                var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error);
                $(data.context.children()[index])
                    .append('<br>')
                    .append(error);
            }
        });
    }).on('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.files, function (index) {
            var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text('File upload failed.');
            $(data.context.children()[index])
                .append('<br>')
                .append(error);
        });
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
        .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
```

Comment: Is the PHP returning with json_encode? Might not be returning json which is what you are using in Ajax request

Comment: Hi Russel - thanks for the thought - when I call the script with a new UploadHandler(); it returns JSON - and infact when I make the call its all working ok - its just the thumbnails I'm struggling with - when the /jQfileUpload/index.html page loads, it fires a GET call and I can't work out how thats working